# Write a function of the log odds of the posterior probabilities (QDA) to see it is quadratic in x.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, logarithms, self-learning, bayesian

I'm reading the *An Introduction to Statistical Learning* book and get stuck at Chapter 4 page 159  where the author(s) state that in the QDA setting, the log odds of the posterior probabilities is quadratic in x:

$$ log \left( \dfrac{Pr(Y = k|X = x)}{Pr(Y = K|X = x)} \right) = a_k + \sum _{j=1}^{p} b_{kj} x_j + \sum _{j=1}^{p} \sum _{l=1}^{p} c_{kjl} x_j x_l$$

where $$ a_k, b_{kj}, c_{kjl} $$ are functions of $$ \pi_k , \pi_K, \mu_k, \mu_K, \Sigma_k, \Sigma_K $$

In exercise 11 (page 192), I am asked to work out the form of $$ a_k, b_{kj}, c_{kjl} $$ and I have no idea how to start. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Link for the book: https://hastie.su.domains/ISLR2/ISLRv2_website.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Ratio of posteriors gives
$$
\frac{\pi_k \sqrt{|\mathbf{\Sigma}_K|}}
{\pi_K \sqrt{|\mathbf{\Sigma}_k|}}
\exp 
\left[
-
\frac12 (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{m}_k)^T 
\mathbf{\Sigma}_k^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{m}_k)
+\frac12 (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{m}_K)^T 
\mathbf{\Sigma}_K^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{m}_K)
\right]
$$
Taking log yields
$$
a
+
\frac12
\left[
(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{m}_K)^T 
\mathbf{\Sigma}_K^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{m}_K)
-
(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{m}_k)^T 
\mathbf{\Sigma}_k^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{m}_k)
\right]
=
a
+
\frac12
\left[
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{x}
+
\mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{x}
+
c
\right]
$$
You are asked to make explicit the scalars $a,c$, the vector $\mathbf{b}$ and the symmetric matrix $\mathbf{Q}$. I leave it to you to do the calculations from here.